# Handling FTP errors via subprocess in Python

Tags: python, exception, ftp, subprocess

I want to handle FTP error codes ran in a subprocess that is run as part of this python script so in essence if the FTP command returns code 550 file not found I want to somehow handle this exception in python but I'm not 100% sure how to do this any direction would be appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import ftplib
import os
import subprocess
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--ftp', help='FTP address to retrieve DA from', dest='ftpconn', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--user', help='FTP username', dest='user', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--password', help='FTP password', dest='passwd')
parser.add_argument('--file', help='File(s) to retrieve', dest='file', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', help='Destination folder for transferred files, if left blank default directory will be the working directory', default='./', dest='dfolder')
args = parser.parse_args()


command = """user %s %s
cd ..
lcd %s
get %s
bye"""


for idx, item in enumerate(args.file):
    pobj = subprocess.Popen(['ftp', '-nv', args.ftpconn], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    pobj.communicate(command % (args.user, args.passwd, args.dfolder, args.file[idx]))
```

Comment: unrelated: why do you use `ftp` command instead of `ftplib` module that you have imported?

Comment: I wasn't very experienced with ftplib so was using retrbinary and then scratching my head when I wasn't getting plaintext documents out the other end, then I read the documentation and realised retrlines is what I actually wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` object returns the output and error

```
    sStdout, sStdErr = probj.communicate(your_command)
```

More over you can get the return code of the process object by:

```
    nRetCode = probj.returncode
```

A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.

A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).

Comment: Even if the transfer fails the returncode still shows 0 though because im guessing the subprocess as a whole is successful.

Comment: Yeah it is just the return code for `subprocee.probj` object. just modified the answer

Comment: So do you know of a way to get the return code of the FTP command made available to python without doing string manipulation on stdout/stderr?

Comment: Sorry for late reply I read the docs more deeply and found that `prob.communicate` sets the `probj.returncode` as is returned by `probj.wait()`(`wait()` returns the returncode of child process) that means you should get the return code of child process in your case too. I tried his with python script and using `sys.exit(45)` in it and I got value of `probj.returncode` as `45`. Can you try running an individual process(which you know fail) and see what return code you get...

Comment: Hey I tried that nd I got a return code of 0 no matter if the file was successfully transferred or not.

Comment: Can you tell me what is passed as `args.ftpconn`?

Comment: it is just the IP address of the mainframe, obviously for security I cant post the exact address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81506/discussion-between-shaktimaan-and-basichorizon).

Comment: it is blocked at my place of work, I have found a solution by changing my design and using ftplib(I originally thought ftplib was not an option but it is now an option and I just handle the exception normally. thanks for the help a lot though it was appreciated very much so!